# How to draw open end curve shapes in Threejs

Tags: three.js, geometry, shapes, curve

I am drawing curves/polygons by using ExtrudeBufferGeometry.
Usually it always has closed ends.
For example:
[image]

My target is to draw similar shapes but open ended like

[image]
[image]

Note that my target is not "**LINES**" or "**Planes**". It must have extrude and I just want continuous points keep combining with angle (angle can be any floating point value in radian)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution lies [in the ExtrudeGeometry documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=extr#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry), where it states:

> When creating a Mesh with this geometry, if you'd like to have a separate material used for its face and its extruded sides, you can use an array of materials. The first material will be applied to the face; the second material will be applied to the sides.

So when generating the mesh, just pass 2 materials, the first one with `visible: false` so it doesn't get rendered.

```js
const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );

const materialFace = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { visible: false } );
const materialSide = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [materialFace, materialSide] ) ;
```

Comment: I also use another way like `curveShape.holes.push(curveShape)`. Which works but shape must be positively created. Your method works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: But it is still **Closed Shape**. Isn't it possible to create shape with **Open End**?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think `ExtrudeGeometry` was built with that feature.